# Why "http.Get()" method is throwing fatal exception in go?

Tags: http, go

I am trying to use the following method:

```
response,err:=http.Get("https://support.microsoft.com")
```

It is working as expected. But when I call it with **"https://samsung.com"**, it is throwing fatal exception that I can not handle.

A code sample:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    _, err := http.Get("http://support.microsoft.com")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

and here is the error:

```
panic: cipher.NewCBCEncrypter: IV length must equal block size
goroutine 55 [running]:
crypto/cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(0x7c7680, 0xc0001cd0b0, 0xc0000c03c8, 0x10, 0x20, 0x0, 0x0)
C:/Go/src/crypto/cipher/cbc.go:47 +0x139  
crypto/tls.cipherAES(0xc0000c0388, 0x20, 0x60, 0xc0000c03c8, 0x10, 0x20, 0x0, 0x20, 0xc00008c156)  
C:/Go/src/crypto/tls/cipher_suites.go:139 +0xe2  
crypto/tls.(*clientHandshakeState).establishKeys(0xc0001dfdc8, 0x0, 0x0)  
C:/Go/src/crypto/tls/handshake_client.go:625 +0x20c  
crypto/tls.(*clientHandshakeState).handshake(0xc0001dfdc8, 0xc0000b7200, 0x0)  
C:/Go/src/crypto/tls/handshake_client.go:402 +0x426  
crypto/tls.(*Conn).clientHandshake(0xc00003dc00, 0x0, 0x0)  
C:/Go/src/crypto/tls/handshake_client.go:208 +0x2d4  
crypto/tls.(*Conn).Handshake(0xc00003dc00, 0x0, 0x0)  
C:/Go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:1343 +0xf6  
net/http.(*persistConn).addTLS.func2(0x0, 0xc00003dc00, 0xc0000cc7d0, 0xc000093da0)  
C:/Go/src/net/http/transport.go:1190 +0x49  
created by net/http.(*persistConn).addTLS  
C:/Go/src/net/http/transport.go:1186 +0x1b2
```

Comment: It did not return any error, can you share the full code or the error your are getting?

Comment: There are no exceptions in Go, much less fatal exceptions that cannot be handled. Add the exact error message to the question.

Comment: i just edit question and added error. thanks

Comment: is error log enough?

Comment: I can not reproduce this error, neither calling the code with `go run main.go` nor with a compiled version. You might want to check `GOPATH` and `GOROOT` environment variables.

Comment: can you show output of `go env` and `go version` and OS ? here they all works (both http and https go version = 1.12.4). can you try microsoft website with httpS and show the result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just fixed my problem by updating go from 1.12.4 to 1.12.5.
thanks to @Markus-W-Mahlberg